# Get Accent color like Windows 10

Tags: .net, vb.net, image

When I change Desktop Wallpaper in Windows 10, Windows automatically generates an Accent color.

In vb.net, I want a similar technique, i.e., getting the accent color of an image just like windows.

Is it possible? How?

Please consider forwarding some examples.

Comment: Microsoft intentionally does not document this.  Along with anything else that is likely to change in the next major UI refresh.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Is the OP referring to this: [DwmGetColorizationColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetcolorizationcolor), which could map to this: [SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.windowglasscolor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_SystemParameters_WindowGlassColor)?

Comment: I know how to get current accent color by calling some api of uxtheme.dll. Actually one of my apps has the code. This is not what I need. For example, I have background image for a .net form and I need to calculate the accent color of the image and it will be used as forecolor of labels used in that form.